# Label to secondary axis in R

Tags: r, glmnet

What is the right way to change the font size for the labels of the plots?

For example

```
library(glmnet)
library(plotmo) #plot_glmnet

windowsFonts(A = windowsFont("Times New Roman"))
plot_glmnet(lasso.mod, main ="Lasso", label=5, #5 variable more important
            xlab= "Log(λ)", 
            ylab="Coefficients",
            cex.lab = 1.25,
            cex.axis = 1.25,
            cex.main = 1.25,
            family="A")
```

The secondary axis adds automatically, and I wonder if I could change it.

[image]

Comment: plot_glmnet is from plotmo package, it has no option of adjusting cex for secondary axis.

Comment: In almost every case, it's better to learn how to do this in `ggplot2` rather than try to find a workaround. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75442304/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-ggplot2-version-of-a-x-y-loglambda-coefficien) is a goodish place start, then look up how to modify axis labels etc. using `ggplot2`. The link also some base R solutions.

Answer (score 1):

First- I would check the function's documentation thoroughly with `?plot_glmnet` to see if there's an option to do this in the function.
If the unwanted axis is added automatically in a way that can not be modified- I would go to the code in the github page: https://github.com/cran/plotmo/blob/master/R/plot_glmnet.R

copy the code that makes the function `plot_glmnet` and modify it by making a second function: `plot_glmnet_modified_axis=function(..){....}` then play with the code in this new function until it does what you want it to do.
NOTE: the axis may be set by a different function that plot_glmnet calls- hence you may have to modify that function:

```
     axis_setter_modified=function(..){...}

     plot_glmnet_modified_axis=function(..){axis_setter_modified(....)}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).